# B2C App registration with custom SAML policy - configuring claims

Tags: azure, saml, azure-ad-b2c, idp

I created some custom policy for our SAML applications in Azure b2c.
Now I want to edit the claims sent by azure b2c to application in SAMLResponse.

I added the claims in the trustframwworkbase:

```
  <ClaimType Id="TESTFELDSTRING">
    <DisplayName>TESTFELDSTRING</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="TESTFELDSTRING" />
      <Protocol Name="SAML2" PartnerClaimType="TESTFELDSTRING" />
    </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
    <UserHelpText>Your TESTFELDSTRING name.</UserHelpText>
    <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
  </ClaimType>
```

And I changed my custom policy and added some new outputclaim there:

```
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="TESTFELDSTRING" />
```

But the claim is still missing in my SAML responses.

I have one application which expects some information as SAML Claim and I do not see how to transmit it.
On the "normal Azure AD" I will be able to configure the claims per app. So one app is sending other claims than another app. How to do this in azure b2c?
I tried to add the claim inside the manifest of my app registration with:

```
"optionalClaims": {
    "saml2Token": [
        {
            "name": "TESTFELDSTRING",
            "source": null,
            "essential": false,
            "additionalProperties": []
        }
]
```

}
But this is not working too.
My transmitted attributes are:

```
    <saml:AttributeStatement xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <saml:Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"
                        NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri"
                        FriendlyName="Display Name"
                        >
            <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">XXX</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
        <saml:Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname"
                        NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri"
                        FriendlyName="Given Name"
                        >
            <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">XXX</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
        <saml:Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname"
                        NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri"
                        FriendlyName="Surname"
                        >
            <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">XXX</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
        <saml:Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"
                        NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri"
                        FriendlyName="Email Address"
                        >
            <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">XXX@XXX.XXX</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
        <saml:Attribute Name="objectId"
                        NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"
                        FriendlyName="User's Object ID"
                        >
            <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
    </saml:AttributeStatement>
```

Anyone a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you follow this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/connect-with-saml-service-providers)?

Did you add the new claims as output claims in the Technical profile?

Did you also add the new claims as output claims in the `<RelyingParty>` section?

Comment: Thanks for answer.
yeah, i followed that howto.

I figured out, that adding claims inside the TechnicalProfile will work. My problem was, that I did not configured the new fields properly. Got some error with this manual: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-custom-attributes

I will ask a new question about the second problem: how to define claims per app.